# Fish shell - How to interpolate a subcommand?

Tags: interpolation, fish

In bash I can say:

```
$ echo "a$(echo b)c"
abc
```

How do I do this in the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com)?

Comment: `echo a(echo b)c`... see http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
echo a(echo b)c
```

If you have quotes, you must exit them:

```
echo "a"(echo b)"c"
```

If your subcommand may have newlines, as of fish 2.3, you have to save and restore $IFS:

```
set -l IFS 
echo "a"(cat ~/file.txt)"c"
set -e IFS
```

Eventually `string` will be able to handle this case.

Comment: This will somehow swallow all newline characters and does not seem to be equivalent. Minimal example: Given `echo -e "a\nb" > x` then bash `echo "$(cat x)"` does the right thing whereas fish `echo (cat x)` will transform the newline to a space (which would be equivalent to bash `echo $(cat x)` without the quotes).

Comment: Is there still no way of doing this other than setting `IFS` to empty?

Comment: `string collect` is now available to avoid newline splitting. Example usage: `echo (cat x | string collect)`